# jquery How to put "appends" from $.each to <li> tag

Tags: jquery

I have this each in jquery which gets answers and user chooses one from radio box, everything works fine, except i would like to put every pass in a <**li**> tag.

```
$.each(questions.answers, function(key, val) {

    $(".exam").append(
        $('<input />', {
            type: 'radio',
            name: 'answer',
            id: val.id,
            value: val.text
        })
    );
    $(".exam").append(
        $('<label />', {
            'text': val.text,

        })

    );
    $(".exam").append('</br>');

});
```

This gives out:

```
<input id="val.id" type="radio" name="answer" value="val.text"><label>val.text</label><br>
```

I would like to get:

```
<li><input id="val.id" type="radio" name="answer" value="val.text"><label>val.text</label></li>`
```

i cant seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first append the li element and then append input text and label in it.

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
   $.each(questions.answers, function (key, val) {
                $('.exam').append('<li/>');
                $(".exam li:last").append(
                        $('<input />', {
                            type: 'radio',
                            name: 'answer',
                            id: val.id,
                            value: val.text
                        })
                        );
                $(".exam li:last").append(
                        $('<label />', {
                            'text': val.text,

                        })

                        );

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to create an li element first, append to the li element, and then append the complete element to .exam:

```
$.each(questions.answers, function (key, val) {

                    var li = $("<li>");
                    li.append(
                            $('<input />', {
                                type: 'radio',
                                name: 'answer',
                                id: val.id,
                                value: val.text
                            })
                            );
                    li.append(
                            $('<label />', {
                                'text': val.text,

                            })

                            );
                    $(".exam").append(li);
                });
```